# Spring 4 MVC Project without Maven

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

Does anyone have working project template with the following:

- Spring 4.x MVC
- Spring Security 4.x
- Spring Data JPA 1.8.x
- Hibernate 4.3.x

Unfortunately, I cannot use Maven currently and it is a pain to track down all of the dependencies.

Comment: You could look at using Spring Boot.  If that's not an option you could just set up a temporary Maven project that pulls down all the dependencies and then move them from your Maven .m2 directory to your real project's WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I cannot get it to download the libraries because the connection times out due to the firewall.

Comment: That's not really a Maven problem, you'll need to pull the dependencies down from somewhere regardless of the tools you're using. The only other option is if the company has a local artifact repository of some type on the network that has the dependencies you require or can get past the firewall to pull them down for you.

Comment: your firewall doesn't allow http?

Comment: It does, it's just sometimes the proxy is a pain to work with. I was eventually able to get maven finally working. I had to delete the entire repository several times before it finally started working. I don't know why, I had setup the settings.xml to negotiate the proxy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to get maven finally working. I had to delete the entire repository several times before it finally started working